# Export to FBX not available

Tags: export

for some unknown reason (to me) most of the export options with the file I am working now dissapeared. But with other files all export options are available. Is it a bug or how could I enable it for my working file???

[image]

in the same working file, if I switch to Layout mode the export options are back, and if I switch to modeling the options disappear again, is that intended?

Edit.. this behaviour happens only with my working file, with other files I have all export options in Modeling and Layout modes

Comment: you can check the console to see if there is any error, **Window > Toggle System Console**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized the problem, and it is super noob but I will leave the solution here in case another new to Blender artist faces this xD

[image]

For some reason I had activated this,  once I disabled it all works back to normal

shame

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with your user preferences. FBX import/export is an add-on there.

Comment: it is enabled :/  it is just so weird, I am kinda new in Blender so not sure wtf is going on, but havent experienced this with any other model or in previous versions of the blender 2.8 beta